# Help me with "template parameters not used in partial specialization"

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I've been struggling with NOT C++0x code, but regular C++. Don't ask me why I have to use regular C++, it's just some kind of silly requirement.

So here's the thing : I need to get a value in an enum to be 1 or 0, regarding that some statement is true or false.
So of course, I templated a struct containing 0 in an enum, specializated it with the second statement where the enum contains 1 instead of 0.

Seems quite legit to me, however, it tells me that I should use the parameters of the specialization. Which is kinda strange, because I tried to use it in all possible ways and it just kept popping out this error.

Here's the code :

```
  template<typename T>
  struct CanPrint
  {
    template<size_t>
    struct Value               { enum { val = 0 }; };

    template<size_t>
    struct Value<sizeof(True)> { enum { val = 1 }; };

    enum
    { value = Value<sizeof(IsTrue<T>(0))>::val };
  };
```

I bet this would work if it wasn't a partial specialization, but explicit ones can't be at namespace-scope. And I obviously can't specialize a template within a template without specializing both of them. Can I ?

Comment: The answers explain how to make things wokr, but judging by the name, you just want a type that says something is printable or not based on the specialisations you have defined, in which case you just need `template <class T> struct CanPrint { enum { value = 0 }; };` as the primary template, then for each printable type, define `template <> struct CanPrint<MyType> { enum { value = 1 }; };`  I cant think of a way to detect `operator<<` automatically without C++11.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<>  //<---- leave it empty
struct Value<sizeof(True)> { enum { val = 1 };
```

By the way, its not partial specialization if `True` isn't template argument. It is full specialization .

And since this is full specialization, you cannot define it inside the class, i.e at class-scope. Full specialization  can be defined only at namespace-scope. So define `Value` , primary well as the specialization, at namespace scope.

Or, you can do this instead:

```
template<typename T>
struct CanPrint
{
    //modified
    template<typename U, size_t N = sizeof(U)> 
    struct Value { enum { val = 0 }; };

    //modified - now its partial specialization
    template<typename U>    
    struct Value<U, sizeof(True)> { enum { val = 1 }; };

    enum { value = Value<IsTrue<T> >::val }; //modified here as well
};
```

See the online demo : http://www.ideone.com/MSG5X

Comment: Indeed. Yet I can't make a full specialization inside a namespace-scope. Do I really HAVE to get out of that namespace ?

Answer (score 2):

```
template<> // note the empty <>
struct Value<sizeof(True)> { enum { val = 1 }; };
```

You only list parameters for *partial* specializations:

```
template< typename T, typename U> 
struct X;

template<typename U> 
struct X<char,U> {...};

template<typename Z, typename U> 
struct X<std::vector<Z>, U> {...};
```

Not for full specializations:

```
template<> 
struct X<double,int> {...};
```